# Google Sheets: Can I use the label as a variable within a link?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to reference value of a cell with a link, so you just have to update the label, and the link will follow?

Like so:

`=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("https://github.com/github-user/",_LINK_LABEL_),"github-repo")`

Where `_LINK_LABEL_` is "github-repo" gets added to the link, and updating the label will update the link also.

Comment: Did you try Data > Named ranges?

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Sheets, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add your link labels in a column (for example this one will be in cell A1)

A1's value is:

github-repo

Then put your formula in cell B1:

=HYPERLINK("https://github.com/github-user/"&A1,A1)